# Searching a working library for rails 2.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

Do you a library like (or the good version of...) Mongoid or MongoMapper working with 
rails-2.1.2 and mongo 1.0 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default not, because Mongoid and MongoMapper need ActiveSupport 2.2.x.

But the difference between ActiveSupport 2.2.x and 2.1.x is not a big deal. So you can try change all dependencies to this activeSupport and try launch all test. See what happen.

Mongo-ruby-driver has no dependencies to ActiveSupport. So you can already use it on your Rails 2.1.x application.